# Asymptotic Expansion of Polynomial

Tags: polynomials, asymptotics

I'm trying to find first two non-zero terms in the asymptotic expansion for each of the three roots of

$\epsilon x^3 - x^2  + x -\epsilon ^{1/2} = 0$

as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0^{+}$.

The naive expansion of the form $x=x_0 +\epsilon x_1 + O(\epsilon^2)$ gave only two roots. How do I attack this? I read about possibly using a Newton-Kruskal diagram but I don't really understand the argument made in this question [Asymptotic expansions for the roots of $\epsilon^2x^4-\epsilon x^3-2x^2+2=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/810031/asymptotic-expansions-for-the-roots-of-epsilon2x4-epsilon-x3-2x22-0) .

I want to rescale the equation by setting $X = x\epsilon^{\nu}$ but, I'm not sure on how to balance this? Do I need to eliminate the $\epsilon^{1/2}$ term?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to deal with the Newton polygon or Laurent/Puiseux series, set $y=\epsilon x$ and $\epsilon=\zeta^2$. Then it is just as well to find series solutions to $$y^3-y^2+\zeta^2 y-\zeta^5=0\text{.}$$
The naïve method will work for this equation.

Comment: Just tried this, still giving only two roots for $y_0$ ?

Comment: The root $y_0=0$ splits at order $\zeta^2$

Comment: Which order did you go to in the naive expansion so that you obtain two terms in the expansion?

Comment: through $\zeta^4$

Comment: Are you using Maple or Mathematica to expand? lol